# Couvrir et recouvrir

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, usage, verbes

Can we only use the verb *recouvrir* when some thing is already covered but not completely?
Or can we use it to tell a person to cover a thing two times, too? ( Note that we told this to the person before he started covering the object. )

Answer (score 5):

You can use *recouvrir* to mean:

- Cover something for the first time, here the prefix *re-* is an intensifier.
  *Le vésuve a recouvert Pompeï de cendres volcaniques.*
- Cover something already covered, the prefix *re-* means 'again', for example *recouvrir un livre*: you put an extra cover one on top of the original one to protect it.
  *On demande aux élèves de recouvrir les livres que l'école leur prête au début de l'année.*

Comment: +1 Also, to avoid ambiguity in a conversation about covering something twice, you might have to say "couvrir encore une fois" or "re-couvrir" with an emphasis on "re".

Comment: Thank you so much ☕, so when re is used as an intensifier it means to completely cover some thing, right ?

Comment: It does indeed unless you say *recouvre partiellement*.